# booting HP ProLiant DL160 Gen8 in uefi

Tags: windows-server-2016, hp-proliant, bios, uefi

I recently got a DL 160 gen8 and I'm trying to boot windows from a 3TB drive. the  windows Installer is refusing to install windows on gpt partitions. So I need to boot in uefi.

I looked everywhere but I can't find any bios configuration options! I don't see where  the bios boot options are...

I even started to wonder if my server is even capable of UEFI. The manufacturer's official website(hpe's website) does not mention anything about uefi in gen8, only in gen 9 documentation but the server provider confirmed that my server supports uefi. It's a bit confusing

Could you please help me to figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just contacted HPE. They confirmed, DL160 G8 (and most G8 servers in general) does not have uefi. The only exception is DL580 gen8.

Comment: You're correct about Gen8, it does not have UEFI support. We only support UEFI in Gen9 and newer.